# Polars - efficiently partition large dataset

Tags: python, python-polars

I need to partition large CSV dataset into smaller year-month partitions. What I do:

```py
for year in range(2016, 2019):
    year_df = (pl
        .scan_csv('some.csv', infer_schema_length=100000, null_values=['\\N'], cache=True)
        .with_columns(
            pl.col('origin_datetime').dt.year().alias('year'),
            pl.col('origin_datetime').dt.month().alias('month')
        )
        .filter((pl.col('year') == year))
        .cache()
    )
    for month in range(1,13):
        (year_df
            .filter((pl.col('month') == month))
            .collect(streaming=True)
            .write_parquet(f'/{year}_{month}.parquet')
        )
```

so I thought I could cache data for every year and therefore then filtering for each month would be fast but it seems every month still take about the same time. Is there any way to improve this?

Comment: This is probably a better task for pyarrow's dataset writer. Have you looked at it?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably slow because it needs to scan the entire data frame 12 times, once for each month. It's more efficient to let Polars do the grouping for you.

Take a look at [`DataFrame.partition_by`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.partition_by.html):

```
for (year, month), month_df in df.partition_by(['year', 'month'], as_dict=True):
    month_df.write_parquet(f'{year}_{month}.parquet')
```

I didn't test this so it probably won't work as-is, but hopefully you can figure it out from here.

Comment: LazyFrame doesn't have partition_by, only DataFrame does. If they're scanning their csv then they have LazyFrame. Presumably their csv is too big to fit in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your scan of the csv out of the loop. Also you don't need to do any cacheing since all you're doing is saving files. A use case for cacheing is you do some calculation and you know you'll need the results again so you cache them. That's not what you're doing so you don't need it.

```
lf=(
    pl.scan_csv('some.csv', infer_schema_length=100000, null_values=['\\N'])
        .with_columns(
            pl.col('origin_datetime').dt.year().alias('year'),
            pl.col('origin_datetime').dt.month().alias('month')
        )
)
for year in range(2016, 2019):
    for month in range(1,13):
        (lf
            .filter(
              (pl.col('month') == pl.lit(month)) & 
              (pl.col('year') == pl.lit(year))
             )
             ## maybe add .drop(['month','year']) here as they're redundant columns
            .collect() # you can try streaming if you run into OOM
            .write_parquet(f'/{year}_{month}.parquet')
        )
```